# Using a before filter or staying in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my controller actions, i almost always have different checks that set flash errors and redirect, like :

```
def create
    flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.no_resources') and redirect_to research_center_url and return if not resource_report[:has_resources]

    flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.no_deps') and redirect_to research_center_url and return if not research.fulfil_requirements?(active_city)
    ...
end
```

This works fine, but i thought that maybe checking checking those in my model for before_create is better than having the checks in the controller(though the flash messages should generally be in a controller).

However, i cannot really put these checks in my models, since they contain non model related information that i cannot really fetch normally. So my question is, how do you check your controllers for normal application related errors that are not exceptions and have to be flashed back to a user ? Do you make the checks in the controller as i do here, via model callbacks or some other way ?

Answer (score 1):

DRYest way to use a before_filter for many but not all of your controller files is to use a before_filter and subclass ApplicationController.

This enables you to have multiple controller files that automatically share the same set of before_filters

In this example, I'm calling the subclass FrontController. You can use any name.

eg

```
class FrontController < ApplicationController
# Used for all "frontend" controllers which have the same checks. 

  before_filter :standard_checks
  # standard_checks will be a before filter for all controllers that
  # inherit from this controller class
end
```

then

```
class SomeController < FrontController 

  def create 
    ....
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that the checks are not standard. Some of them are about levels, others about requirements, others about roles and so on. But for some of the checks that have a same pattern, i like the idea +1.

Comment: To me, using filters isn't just about DRY code, but also keeping controller actions lean. Also, what you're doing with those flash messages is precisely that--filtering out and preventing the action from being called before you even get there.